how can get page managment and page read permission with facebook login app?
I am having trouble obtaining the pages_read_engagement and pages_show_list and ... permissions for my Facebook app. I just created the app and selected the Facebook Login type, but the only permissions available in the use cases are email and user_profile.
I want to create an app that can automatically reply to comments with direct messages, so I need the following permissions:

pages_show_list

pages_read_engagement
and ...


Here are the steps I have taken so far:

Created a new Facebook app.

Selected "Facebook Login" as the type.

Tried to configure permissions but only saw options for email and user_profile.


How can I add the necessary permissions for my app? Is there a specific process or additional steps I need to follow to request these permissions?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated.
